# Spring cannot initialize bean in profile "dev"

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, profile

My code throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'Unknown' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:686)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
    at core.Main.main(Main.java:38)
```

I am using mixed configuration - XML and Annotation based:

**Dev context:**

```
<beans profile="dev">

    <context:component-scan base-package="core"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <import resource="classpath:beans/beans.xml"/>

</beans>
```

**Beans.xml context:** contains other beans which are initialized in XML - no annotations used there.

```
<beans profile="dev,default">
   <bean ...
   <bean ...
</beans>
```

And here is problematic **Configuration** (please note the comment below):

```
@Configuration
@Profile({"dev"})
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean(value="Unknown")
    @Description("Bean for unknown user")
    public User getUnknownUser() {
        User user = new User(-1);
        user.setUsername("Unknown");
        return user;
    }
}
```

Spring correctly initializes beans defined in XML - these beans is in `default` profile. Only the unknown user is in `dev` profile.

**Main class:**

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("dev.xml");
applicationContext.getEnvironment().acceptsProfiles("dev");
User unknown = (User)applicationContext.getBean("Unknown");
LOGGER.info(unknown.toString());
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please show also the configuration of `default`.

Comment: that is not necessary: By default Spring always runs in the "default" profile, but there are no other special profiles defined by Spring.

Comment: Maybe you missunderstood how profiles work.  You should have a separate `profile-config.xml` for each profile.

Comment: I think that it is just a convention to use file-based profiles

Comment: ..and also it is better not to mix `xml` and `java` based configurations.

Comment: another convention, please, try to answer my question :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179965/discussion-between-niver-and-adam-ostrozlik).

Comment: Ofcourse it won't work if you remove default. Then there is no such bean because that is only available when the dev profile is active.

Comment: @M.Deinum but beans definition says - active profiles dev and default so how cannot be dev profile active?

Comment: Your question is unclear ... When doesn't it work? Your comment states, that is doesn't work when `default` is removed. Which is correct as you. nowhere enable the `dev` profile. Hence obviously it won't work.

Comment: The bean definitions don't state that `default` and `dev` are active it only states that these configuration apply when `default` or `dev` is active.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have edited the source code but not it cannot found even beans in beans.xml

Comment: Because you are setting if after the context has started. Either refresh the context (reloading your whole application!) or set it before you call the constructor (with `System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active","dev");` ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered that i was missing this line:

```
    applicationContext.refresh();
```

Works now, thanks